# This usage of “だけ”

Tags: usage, particle-だけ

I sometimes see “〜だけ” in sentences such as:

> 昔から男運だけは悪かった。

The context does not imply “Only my luck with men has always been bad.” and that's a somewhat weird sentence. Is there some other significance to this “〜だけ” here or does it really mean that it's the only thing that was bad and that all other things were good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This だけ does mean "only". The sentence really means that 男運 is the only thing that is bad about her.

> When it comes to men (and men only), my luck has always been bad.

Comment: I see, so the “だけ” part applies to the “男”, not the “運” part but it's simply phrased that way because “男運” is a set word?

Comment: @Zorf 男運 is one word. "When it comes to luck with men" is closer to the original Japanese.

Comment: @Zorf Think of it as, "Luck with men, that's the only thing that's been bad for me"